# SQL Server Data Change Tracking and showing data state in given time

Tags: sql-server, database-design, change-tracking

I have a quite specific problem for which I'm unable to find any workable solution (it is an ASP.NET web application with SQL Server 2008 R2).

Let's say we have 3 elements (tables) with some data. We need to track data changes on these elements.

Today we do it with separate tables with user id, table name, column name, old value, new value, some time stamp etc.

But now we need to be able to show data at any given time, e.g. show elements data in the exact state with exact values like they were e.g. week ago (in exact given time).

Is there any best practice solution for this or anything, that would not require to write a complex T-SQL function/procedure hierarchy (which will always take up very much time) to get the data back together?

Thank you for any advice!

**EDIT:**

Our customer has 700k rows in xls file (4 types of elements mixed together .. nightmare :D ).

We want to process it and maintain it in database.

Then they will change the data in small portions every few days also with physical files. Then they need to be able to "show how it exactly looked like" in given time.

Comment: Huh ... really depends on your data set and how many entrys you need to handle. Maybe it would be possible to make a compound key out of your (existing?) identifier/primary key and a timestamp. That way you could get the 'newest' as current entity state and would also store changes. You could also get all entrys when filtering your table only by pk and see all changes made to an entry. Well redundancy is a problem though.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment - we have initial xls file (which will be imported into db) with 700k rows. It will be synced every few days with all data changes, we estimate some 100-1000 rows changed every few days. So entries will scale pretty fast I think.

Comment: The compound key is quite interesting suggestion - we will try to create a model this way and examine it if it feasible solution in our enviroment, thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome, good luck! =)

Comment: Triggers & and changelog table with primary key of the tracked table, date of modification, and value modified.

Answer (score 0):

By forwarding the suggestion from [nilsK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2590375/nilsk) we moved the suggested compound key to different table, because out time stamp is given by update application proces in given time. Then we duplicated only ID's of elements in binding table, so we minimize data redundancy (not perfectly, but good enough).
 We came up with solution, with which we can:
- show element data in given time (quite fast, only by choosing D1 or D2 from Update table)
- get "life cycle" of any chosen element in time (customer wants to show life cycle of whole element/row)
What we cannot do (which was not a original request for this task, but we used it in past)
- get concrete columns changes on given element fast, because they are not tracked, only element as whole, but if needed can be obtained by tracking back in Element table by ID and ParentID

[image: DB structure]

I don't know, maybe it's a bad approach, but I can't think of anything better which can return "historical" data view fast on demand.
Any suggestions?